# Can I make tools.namespace refresh a namespace regardless of whether it changed?

Tags: clojure

Here's why I want to: I'm using the [HugSQL](https://www.hugsql.org/) library which has a `def-db-fns` macro that is called like this: `(hugsql/def-db-fns "sql/queries.sql")`

Basically, it looks at the sql file and uses that to make function definitions in the namespace the macro is called from. But the problem is if I change `queries.sql`, tools.namespace won't refresh the namespace because the namespace itself didn't change. So I am wondering if there is some way to make tools.namespace always refresh a certain namespace, or else somehow link `queries.sql` as a dependency so that the namespace will refresh when it changes.

edit: So far the best solution I've come up with is this:

```
(ns user
  (require [clojure.java.shell :refer [sh]]
           [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :as tns]))

(defn refresh []
  (sh "touch" "src/project_name/queries.clj")
  (tns/refresh))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `refresh-all` instead of `refresh`: it refreshes *all* namespaces regardless of when they changed.

I didn’t find anything in the docs regarding marking a specific namespace as "always reload".

---

You *could* hack this by `touch`ing the file to set its modification date in the future so it’ll always "be modified" after the last `refresh` check but that’ll be reset if you edit the file by yourself and/or break other tools that watch for changes:

```
# set the modified date in the year 3000
touch -m -t 300001010101 queries.clj
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with `refresh-all` is that it is overkill, especially if I have state in other namespaces that I want to keep.

Comment: @pixelperfect I edited my answer with a `touch` hack, but outside of that I don’t see anything in `tools.namespace`’s code to do what you want :/